# Foreach instead for loop

Tags: r, multithreading, for-loop, foreach, time-series

I have a large database and I wrote a code which executes the same calculations on that in a rolling manner by nesting it in a for loop. My problem is that the code runs pretty long. As I read, this is probably caused by R using a single-threaded method as default. As far as I know, foreach package would make it possible to speed up the execution by considerable time, however, I am unsure how to implement it. Currently, my code looks like this, in every iteration I subset a chunk of the large database and do various stuff with these subsets. At the end of an iteration, I collect the output in a time series. Is it possible to apply foreach in this situation?

```
(k in seq(1,5284, 21)) {
   fdata <- data[k:(k+251),]
   tdata <- data[(k+252):(k+377),]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you tag your questions with the appropriate language tag (`r`?) to ensure they get seen by the maximum number of people.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly doable using `foreach`. Depending on your OS you would first have to load a suitable backend (e.g. SNOW on a windows machine) and then set up a cluster.

**Example:**

```r
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

# set number of cores/CPUs to be used
(n_cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1)

# some example data
dat <- matrix(1:1e3, ncol = 10)

# a set you iterate over
k <- 1:99

# run stuff in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
  
  result <- foreach(k) %dopar% {

    fdata <- dat[k:(k+1), ]
    # do computationally expensive stuff with `fdata`
    # ... and return something
    cumsum(fdata[1,] + fdata[2,])

  }

stopCluster(cl)
```

By default `result` will be a list of the results. There are, however, ways to combine into an array or similar. Look at details on the `.combine` argument in `?foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, it works in that manner, that it really speedens up the computation, however for me it is imperfect. It does not really iterate through k, but uses only the first element, consequenlty it does only for the first subset many times